# Determining whether signal is power or energy from autocorrelation

Tags: random

I want to know whether it is possible to determine whether a signal is power or energy from it's autocorrelation function. If this is possible, please explain the method in detail.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing).

Comment: @polfosol I am sorry but I couldn't find a relation between my question and the link you added, can you please explain?

Comment: It is exactly about autocorrelation for energy and power signals. What else do you expect?